# Angular 2 slow initial load

Tags: javascript, angular

When I enable cross origin resource sharing my app takes 8-9 sec to load. When its disabled takes like 1-2 sec. I am really new at this. Any ideas what could be the main problem? And how to speed it up? The project is in really early stage and 8 sec its really long time since the app is not making any requests for data now.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    System.import('app/js/bootstrap')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
   <script src="app/js/xml2json.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/div.js"></script>
        <script src="app/js/divY.js"></script>

    <style>
  body,html{width:100%;height:100%;padding:5px;margin:0;}

  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/interact.js/1.2.6/interact.min.js"></script>
  </head>


  <body>
    <app>
    loading...
  </app>
  </body>

</html>
```

And here is my config.js

```
System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {
    'app': "./app",
    'ng2-translate': 'npm:ng2-translate',
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',

    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js'
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './bootstrap.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'ng2-translate': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }


});
```

Comment: Check your folder and your routing to them. Are you storing in app/js... Is yor selector de proper one in your ts? (app)

Comment: your are importing the whole rxjs library do you need all the classes in rxjs?

Comment: that helped a lot. Now I am seeing many req from zone.js.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Here is the working file. I removed rxjs from map and added it to path

```
System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/',
    'rxjs*': 'https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/dist/global/Rx.js'
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {
    'app': "./app",
    'ng2-translate': 'npm:ng2-translate',
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',

    // 'rxjs':  'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12',
    'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js'
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './bootstrap.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'ng2-translate': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }


});
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, got a load of file not found errors when I switched to your suggested approach

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to zone.js, zone.js is causing an angular websites to have a poor loading and penalize by google speed as script valuation. Check your polyfill.ts and zone.js you can exclude from that file and load directly on the index.html as cloudflare cdn script.